# How can I get permutations with 3 or 4 digits using itertools?

Tags: python

```
from itertools import permutations 
print(list(permutations(range(1,6))))
```

this only gives 5 digit numbers, but I want 3 digit and 4 digit as well.
Output from this code is like 12543, 45321 etc. All this just gives 5 digit number.
Output I want is 123, 312, 4321, as well as 23415 etc. I want all the possible numbers of 3 digits, 4 digits and 5 digits

Comment: Please update your question with your required output.

Comment: I have edited it pls refer

Comment: Since you now know how to get the desired result for 5 digits, can you not just write a loop that repeats the same code but instead of for 5, for 3 and then for 4 digits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there exists an `r` parameter, e.g. `itertools.permutations([1,2,3], r=2)`, which will generate all possible permutations selecting 2 elements: `[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2)]`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so just ask for all the lengths separately:

```py
p = []
for i in range(4, 7):
    p += list(permutations(range(1, i)))

for item in p:
    print(item)
```